# Get all characters except hyphen and brackets from string using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have a string like this:

```
var myString = "MyString-[ADDAAD]-isGreat";
```

I want to extract this string into 3 parts:

```
var stringOne = "MyString-";
var stringTwo = "ADDAAD";
var stringThree = "-isGreat";
```

I know how to get the string between the two square brackets:

```
var matches = patternString.match(/\[(.*?)\]/);
```

now `matches[1]` contains `ADDAAD`
But how can I get the other two parts?

Comment: what is the rule of matching/splitting? For ex. we can split by `-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may *split* the string with your regex. Note that all the capturing group contents will be also part of the resulting array. To avoid empty items, you may add `.filter(Boolean)` after `split()`.

See a JS demo below:

```js
var myString = "MyString-[ADDAAD]-isGreat";
console.log(myString.split(/\[(.*?)]/).filter(Boolean));
console.log("s1-[s2]".split(/\[(.*?)]/).filter(Boolean));
```

**Note** you do not have to escape a `]` used outside character classes, it is always parsed as a literal closing bracket if there is no corresponding `[` before it.

Comment: I got an array .. but I also get "undefined" after the array result.. Please update your answer - correct regex is this: myString.split(/\[(.*?)]/);

Comment: @goldlife: My regex is correct. What string yields "undefined"? Just drop a comment with exact data you are using and I will see to it. Right now, I do not have a slightest idea what your issue is.

Comment: yes .. your regex is correct.. but your syntax was not .. ::-), there was a ")" more then needed, and this causes the problem. I see, you have updated your answer :). thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Select every character except `-`, `[` and `]` using bottom regex.

```js
var myString = "MyString-[ADDAAD]-isGreat";
var parts = myString.match(/[^-\[\]]+/g);
console.log(parts);
```

So if you want to store values in custom variable, use bottom code

```
var stringOne = parts[0];
var stringTwo = parts[1];
var stringThree = parts[2];
```

Comment: thanks, but I need the '-' in the strings... I only want to extract the [] part and store the 3 parts in variables.